# HTTP/1 to HTTP/2 translation via proxy

Tags: http, proxy, http2, http-proxy

I have a legacy client application that supports HTTP/1 protocol only.

Some of the servers accessed by this application no longer support the HTTP/1 protocol because they migrated to the HTTP/2 protocol.

Is it possible to translate the requests made from a client HTTP/1 to a server HTTP/2 using a proxy application such as NGINX?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. I'm sure it's possible to use NGNIX. I also have successfully used [H2O](https://github.com/h2o/h2o)). You would use a configuration file (assuming your legacy app listens on port :8080):

```
access-log: /dev/stdout
listen: 80
listen:
  port: 443
  ssl:
    certificate-file: server.crt
    key-file: server.key
hosts:
  "*":
    paths:
      /:
        proxy.reverse.url: http://127.0.0.1:8080
```